# Overring of an integrally closed domain that is not integrally closed

Tags: commutative-algebra, dedekind-domain

> Assume that $A$ is an integrally closed integral domain, and $K$ is its fraction field. Is every overring of $A$ between $A$ and $K$ also integrally closed ?

This is known to be true if $A$ is a Dedekind domain, see e.g. Jarden, *Field Arithmetic*, chap. 2.

Comment: For Dedekind domains the overrings are even Dedekind domains. But the integrally closed property of overrings characterizes the Prufer domains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A=K+YK[X,Y]$. We have $Q(A)=K(X,Y)$. To show that $A$ is integrally closed notice that $A\subset K[X,Y]$, and the last ring is integrally closed. If an element $z∈Q(A)$ is integral over $A$, then it is integral over $K[X,Y]$, so it belongs to $K[X,Y]$. Now one can get rid of the part of $z$ which belongs to $A$ and get that $z=f(X)$ is integral over $A$ hence over $K$, so $\deg f=0$.

Now consider $R=K[X^2]+YK[X,Y]$. Clearly $R$ is not integrally closed since $X$ is integral over $R$ and $X\notin R$.