# Is an overring of a UFD a normal domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, integral-domain, unique-factorization-domains

**Old question:**
Let $R$ be a UFD, and $Q(R)$ its field of fractions.

Let $S$ be an overring of $R$, namely, a ring such that $R \subseteq S \subseteq Q(R)$.

> **Question:**
> Is it true that $S$ is a UFD?

Notice that $R=k[x^2]$, $S=k[x^2,x^3]$ is not a counterexample,
since $S$ is not contained in the field of fractions of $R$, $Q(R)=k(x^2)$.

Please see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4123728/when-a-simple-algebraic-ring-extension-of-a-ufd-is-a-ufd) similar question: Here we require that $S \subseteq Q(R)$ (and remove the requirement for simplicity); the answer there presents rings $R \subseteq S$ with $S \not\subseteq Q(R)$.

Thank you very much!

---

**New question:** After receiving several comments, including the following counterexample $k[x,y] \subset k[x,y,y/x] \subset k(x,y)$, I would like to change my question to the following one:

> **New question:** Is $S$ normal, namely, integrally closed in its field of fractions $Q(S)$?

[This](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1973-182-00/S0002-9947-1973-0325599-3/S0002-9947-1973-0325599-3.pdf) and [this](https://www.koreascience.or.kr/article/JAKO201117241417311.pdf) paper are relevant.
If I am not wrong, $(k[x],k(x))$ is a normal pair, namely, every ring $k[x] \subseteq S \subseteq k(x)$ is integrally closed in $k(x)$,
so for $R=k[x]$ the new question has a positive answer.

More generally, if I am not wrong, if $R$ is a Dedekind domain, then $(R,Q(R))$ is a normal pair, hence answers the new question positively.

What about $R=k[x,y]$? Is $(k[x,y],k(x,y))$ a normal pair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R=K[x,y]$ and $S=K[x,y,\frac{y^2}{x^2}]$. Since $\frac yx$ is integral over $S$ and does not belong to $S$ it follows that $S$ is not integrally closed.

Comment: For some reasons that I don't know I wasn't able to come up with this example when I wrote [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1163801/121097), although I was aware of the fact that $k[x,y]$ is not Prufer and has to have an overring which is not integrally closed.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, but $k[x,y/x]$ is isomorphic to a polynomial ring.